# Algorithm/Procedure for finding $\sigma$ such that $\omega=d\sigma$

Tags: integration, algorithms, differential-forms

I know that the Poincare's lemma asserts that under certain conditions a differential form $\omega$ is exact, i.e.  it possesses an antiderivative $\sigma$, such that $\omega=d\sigma$.

But as far as I can tell, the proof does not contain an algorithm for actually finding such an $\sigma$ (at least in the way we sketched the proof in class). So my question is: Is there a general algorithm (in a loose sense, not necessarily something one would implement on a computer) that tells me how do effectively calculate $\sigma$ ?

If there is, could someone please illustrate me its steps on some exact form of a higher degree, like the $2$-form $$\omega=(xydy)\wedge (2zdx+xdz) ?$$

My hope is that that will get me started, so that I'll be able to find antiderivatives on my own.

Comment: Try Stokes' theorem. (This generalizes what you'd do for an exact $1$-form, which is to integrate it.)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan We haven't done Stokes theorem yet. Isn't there a more elementary way to find $\sigma$ ? I'm thinking that perhaps in analogy to solving an exact differential equation (where you have to find an integrating factor) there is also a way to find an antiderivative for $2$-forms.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Ok, I looked up Stokes theorem on the internet: If there's no elementary way to find $\sigma$, how can I apply Stokes theorem to find it ? Over what manifold do I have to integrate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a nice coordinate expression for the form (without singularities), then it is fairly easy. The form you wrote can bw written as:
$$
\omega = y\,dy\wedge (2xz\,dx + x^2\,dz)
$$
Why we isolated $y$ will be clear in a second.

Now: 
$$
d\omega = d(y\,dy)\wedge (2xz\,dx + x^2\,dz) - y\,dy\wedge d(2xz\,dx + x^2\,dz) 
$$

The first term is zero, because $d(y\, dy) = dy\wedge dy = 0$. 
This is why we isolated $y$ (always isolate a coordinate, if you can. It is an overall exact form that decouples from the total form).

We are left with:
$$
d\omega = - y\,dy\wedge d(2xz\,dx + x^2\,dz) = -y\,dy\wedge d(2x - 2x)\,dx\wedge dz = 0
$$

It is crucial that the two terms cancel each other out in the exterior derivative, it means that they are a "Leibniz" term in the form $d\alpha\, \beta +\alpha\, d\beta$, which is $d(\alpha\,\beta)$.

In particular, the term $2xz\,dx$ has a $2x$ that looks a lot like the derivative of the $x^2$ appearing in the second term. Can you see what I mean? So if we rewrite:
$$
\omega = y\,dy\wedge (2xz\,dx + x^2\,dz)
$$

We recognize $d(x^2)=2x\,dx$, and obviously $d(z)=dz$, so:
$$
\omega = y\,dy\wedge (d(x^2)\,z + x^2\,dz) = y\,dy\wedge d(x^2z)
$$

You see that $\omega$ is now clearly the derivative of:
$$
\sigma = y\,dy\,x^2z= x^2yz\,dy
$$

In fact:
$$
d\sigma = d(y\wedge dy)\,x^2z + y\,dy\wedge d(x^2z).
$$

The first term is zero, because $d(y\, dy) = 0$, as we saw.
We are left with:

$$
d\sigma = y\,dy\wedge d(x^2z) = y\,dy\wedge (2xz\,dx + x^2\,dz) = \omega.
$$

I hope it is clear enough, otherwise comment and I'll explain more!

Comment: Oh, another thing. Anti-derivating a form is not equal to integrating. That would be true only for 1-forms, not higher!

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I hadn't checked in for a while, since I gave up hope of seeing one.