# Show a 2-form is exact finding a primitive.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-forms

I have to show that $\omega=-4xy\:\mathrm{d}x\wedge \mathrm{d}y-2xz\:\mathrm{d}z\wedge \mathrm{d}x +2yz\:\mathrm{d}y\wedge \mathrm{d}z$ is exact finding a primitve of $\omega$ (by Poincare lemma I already it is).

Now I'm not sure how can I proceed to solve this. This much I know:

For a 1-form $\eta$ given by $\eta =a\:\mathrm{d}x+b\:\mathrm{d}y+c\:\mathrm{d}z$ I have 
$$\mathrm{d}\eta = \left(\frac{\partial b}{\partial x} -\frac{\partial a}{\partial y}\right)\mathrm{d}x\wedge \mathrm{d}y+\left(\frac{\partial a}{\partial z}\mathrm{d}z - \frac{\partial c}{\partial x}\right)\mathrm{d}z\wedge \mathrm{d}x+\left(\frac{\partial c}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial b}{\partial z}\right)\mathrm{d}y\wedge \mathrm{d}x$$

Thus

$$\frac{\partial b}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial a}{\partial y}=-4xy$$
$$\frac{\partial a}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial c}{\partial x} = -2xz$$
$$\frac{\partial c}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial b}{\partial z} =2yz$$

One of the former exercises I solved let me put $a=0$ or $c=0$ and then find a solution for the remaining variables. Now if I do that, let $a=0$, then this means that

$$\frac{\partial b}{\partial x} = -4xy \implies b = -2x^2y + C_1(y,z)$$
$$\frac{\partial c}{\partial x} = 2xz \implies c=x^2z +C_2(y,z)$$

Now it seems that a solution could be $C_1(y,z)=0$ and $C_2(y,z)=y^2z$ because then $\frac{\partial c}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial b}{\partial z} =2yz$.

Is this correct?.

Now, I'd like to find a general solution for this, how could I do that?. Is this similar to a 1-variable differential equation in the sense that the general solution could be written as the sum of a particular solution and an exact form?; but if that is the case, how can I find the exact form that gives me a general solution?

Comment: I answered a similar problem here, it's not a general formula but maybe it can help you: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/422330/algorithm-procedure-for-finding-sigma-such-that-omega-d-sigma/474951#474951

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a explicit integral formula. See for example the proof of Poincare Lemma at *Calculus in Varieties* (Spivak) or my answer in [Poincaré lemma for star shaped domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2838192/poincar%C3%A9-lemma-for-star-shaped-domain/2838193).