# Poincaré lemma for star shaped domain

Tags: manifolds

I would like to know if someone can help me out to prove the Poincaré lemma for a star shaped domain without using the Stokes theorem.

Comment: Any reason why you want to do this? Is the fundamental theorem of calculus allowed? Because that's also Stokes' theorem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[B. Dacorogna](http://caa.epfl.ch/publications/2016_Poincare(anglais).pdf) has a proof that at least does not invoke the Stokes theorem explicitly.

Comment: Is it a good idea to answer and upvote questions that should rather be on MSE?

Comment: Notice that the proof uses the Leibniz-Newton formula on the line just above the words *"It remains to show (1)"* (page 2) - which is the Stokes formula in disguise.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you help me to find some application of these lemma?
From Mathematics or Physics, I dont mind.

Answer (score 5):

Because the lost link of the accepted answer, I will post a proof here.

**Lemma:** Let be $E\subset{\Bbb R}^n$ star-shaped respect to $0$ and ${\bf F}:E\longrightarrow{\Bbb R}^n$ a $C^1$ vector field. We define:
$$
h:{\Bbb R}^n\longrightarrow{\Bbb R}^n,\qquad  h(x) = tx,\qquad t\in{\Bbb R};
$$
$$
g:[0,1]\longrightarrow{\Bbb R}^n,\qquad g(t) = t{\bf F}(tx),\qquad x\in{\Bbb R}^n;
$$
$$
\phi:E\longrightarrow{\Bbb R},\qquad \phi(x) = {\bf F}(tx)\cdot x = \sum_{i=1}^n F_i(tx) x_i,\qquad t\in{\Bbb R}.
$$
Then, we have the following equalities ($D =$ differential, superscript $t =$ transpose):
$$Dh(x)  = tI;$$
$$g'(t)  = {\bf F}(tx) + t D{\bf F}(tx)x;$$
$$D\phi(x) = t x^t D{\bf F}(tx) + {\bf F}(tx)^t.$$

**Proof:**
The first two are obvious and $D\phi(x)$ is a row vector with components:
$$
\partial_j \phi(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n\partial_j(F_i\circ h)(x) + F_j(tx) = $$
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n x_i\sum_{k=1}^n(\partial_k F_i)(tx)\partial_j h(x)+ F_j(tx) = $$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i(\partial_j F_i)(tx) t+ F_j(tx),$$
so
$$D\phi(x) = (\partial_1\phi(x),\cdots,\partial_n\phi(x)) =$$
$$
t(x_1,\cdots,x_n)
\begin{pmatrix}
\partial_1 F_1(tx)&\dots&\partial_n F_1(tx)\\\
\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\\
\partial_1 F_n(tx)&\dots&\partial_n F_n(tx)
\end{pmatrix}
+ (F_1(tx),\cdots,F_n(tx))
= t x^t D{\bf F}(tx) + {\bf F}(tx)^t.\Box
$$

**Theorem (Poincaré Lemma):** Let be $E\subset{\Bbb R}^n$ star-shaped and ${\bf F}:E\longrightarrow{\Bbb R}^n$ a $C^1$ vector field s.t. for $i,j = 1,\cdots,n: \partial_i F_j = \partial_j F_i$. Then, exists a scalar field (potential of ${\bf F}$) $f:E\longrightarrow{\Bbb R}$ with ${\bf F} = \nabla f$.

**Proof:** WLOG, we can suppose $E$ star-shaped respect to $0$. Let be
$$f(x)=\int_0^1 {\bf F}(tx)\cdot x\,dt.$$
By derivation under the integral sign an the previous lemma,
$$
D f(x) = \int_0^1 D\phi(x)\,dt =
\int_0^1(t x^t D{\bf F}(tx) + {\bf F}(tx)^t)\,dt.
$$
Gradient is simply the transpose of differential and by hypothesis $D{\bf F}(tx)$ is symmetric:
$$
\nabla f(x) = D f(x)^t = \int_0^1(t D{\bf F}(tx)^t x + {\bf F}(tx))\,dt = \int_0^1(t D{\bf F}(tx) x + {\bf F}(tx))\,dt.$$
By the previous lemma again:
$$
\nabla f(x) = \int_0^1 g'(t)\, dt =
g(1) - g(0) = 1{\bf F}(1x) - 0{\bf F}(0x) = {\bf F}(x).\Box
$$

Comment: how do you know to consider the function $x\cdot F(tx)$ ? What is the idea for this incredible move ?

Comment: @PermQi, funny fact: I've already asked for the intuition behind the formula: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3169444/intuition-for-formula-in-proof-of-poincar%c3%a9-lemma

Comment: but which material did you find this formula ?

Comment: @PermQi, I don't remember the exact source. This proof is the standard proof (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555783/first-proof-of-poincar%C3%A9-lemma) without the difforms language.